# How can I select Distinct Values of nvarchar datatype and give them a Rank in this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, rank, nvarchar

I am running `SQL Server 2012` and I have a table named `DateDimension` in my database.
My `DateDimension` Table is a table with 2 columns: Column `date` contain daily dates running from '`2014-01-01`' to '`2019-12-31`' and Column `WeekGroup` is of `nvarchar(100)` datatype.

An extract is given below:

```
date         WeekGroup
2014-01-01   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014
2014-01-02   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014
2014-01-03   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014
2014-01-04   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014
2014-01-05   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014
2014-01-06   Wk 06 Jan 2014-12 Jan 2014
...
```

I now have the following query:

```
SELECT
[date],
[WeekGroup],
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [date] ASC) AS 'Rank'

FROM DateDimension

WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'

ORDER BY [date] ASC
```

My output is as follows:

```
date         WeekGroup                     Rank
2014-01-01   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014     1
2014-01-02   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014     2
2014-01-03   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014     3
2014-01-04   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014     4
2014-01-05   Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014     5
2014-01-06   Wk 06 Jan 2014-12 Jan 2014     6
...
```

I would like to fine tune the above query so that I get the following output, with `distinct` `WeekGroup` and a corresponding `Rank`:

```
WeekGroup                     Rank
Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014     1
Wk 06 Jan 2014-12 Jan 2014     2
...
```

How can I do this on an `nvarchar` variable (`WeekGroup`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave `date` out and aggregate by the week group:

```
SELECT WeekGroup,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MIN([date]) ASC) AS [Rank]
FROM DateDimension
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY WeekGroup
ORDER BY MIN([date]) ASC;
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a CTEand RANK():

```
declare @DateDimension table ([date] date, WeekGroup nvarchar(100))
insert into @DateDimension values
  ('2014-01-01', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
, ('2014-01-02', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
, ('2014-01-03', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
, ('2014-01-04', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
, ('2014-01-05', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
, ('2014-01-06', 'Wk 06 Jan 2014-12 Jan 2014')

;with cte as (
SELECT [WeekGroup], count(*) as count
FROM @DateDimension
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
group by [WeekGroup])
select [WeekGroup], rank() over (order by [count] desc) as [Rank] from cte
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```
   declare @DatA table ([date] date, WeekGroup nvarchar(100))
    insert into @DatA values
      ('2014-01-01', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
    , ('2014-01-02', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
    , ('2014-01-03', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
    , ('2014-01-04', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
    , ('2014-01-05', 'Wk 30 Dec 2013-05 Jan 2014')
    , ('2014-01-06', 'Wk 06 Jan 2014-12 Jan 2014')
    SELECT WEEKGROUP, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.WeekGroup desc) RNK
    FROM (
              SELECT DISTINCT WEEKGROUP FROM @DatA
              WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
         )A
```

Comment: Ok, Or not result ?

Comment: It is giving wrong different results, not ranking most in correct order.

Comment: RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.WeekGroup desc)  i have update this also so check

Comment: No. It is just ordering by the weekgroup, not the count rank. I won't check any more as answers already provided.